# How to convert array with properties to typed object

Tags: arrays, typescript

Here is a MWE:

```
type Obj = {n: number}
type Arr = [number] & Obj

const arr = [1] as Arr
arr.n = 1;

console.log(arr) // [1]
console.log(arr as Obj) // [1]
const b = {};
Object.assign(b, arr);
console.log(b as Obj) // {"0": 1, "n": 1}

// expected result: {n: 1}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwHYC4oYK4C2cEATgL4CwAUKJFAIIkkpQDa+RpAulAGSyJq1AMYB7DAGdgUAIZMWrAIw8ZEhk2pySAOgwtFAbiFUxk0QBsI286IDmACi0BKEeIkWrNh1tlr4CFxM3aTgWNDIjKn8IYWBtVQkAS1sMezgAGlkmJ0jTd0trOzTfAQCgA)

In other words, when receiving a type `Arr` I'd like to be able to cast it to `Obj`.

I'm looking for an *automatic* cast, ie a solution only using types and high-level functions, not based on this specific type. In other words

```
b = {n: arr.n}
```

is not acceptable but I would also be pleased with something like

```
b = {k: arr[k] for k in Obj} // does not make sense but just to illustrate the diff with above
```

#### Some more context

In my problem the type I'm receiving (using ethers.js) is always like an array with named properties that are exactly the same as the one in the array, but with a name. In my test (using chai=4.3.4), I don't want to do

```
expect({n: arr.n}).to.deep.eq(expectedValue)
```

for each property.

For example, function signature could be

```
  tokenMetadata(
    pointer: string,
    items: BigNumberish[],
    overrides?: CallOverrides
  ): Promise<
    [
      string,
      string,
      string,
      ([string, string] & { trait_type: string; value: string })[]
    ] & {
      image: string;
      description: string;
      name: string;
      attributes: ([string, string] & { trait_type: string; value: string })[];
    }
  >
```

and the arrayish part of it just bothers me

Comment: I'd probably just do something like `const rexDigits = /^\d+$/; const check = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr).filter(([key]) => !rexDigits.test(key)));
expect(check).to.deep.equal(expectedValue);` but that isn't typesafe. Good luck with it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair enough, I could accept this as an answer would you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like at runtime you want to extract the non-array properties of an augmented array so you can use them with:

```
expect(theObjectPartsOnly).to.deep.eq(expectedValue)
```

...without having to write each one out individually:

```
// Not like this:
expect({x: arr.x}).to.deep.eq(expectedValue)
expect({y: arr.y}).to.deep.eq(expectedValue)
expect({z: arr.z}).to.deep.eq(expectedValue)
```

Since the type of the object probably isn't important at that point, I think I'd probably not worry about the TypeScript part and just handle it at the runtime level, something like this:

```
const rexDigits = /^\d+$/;
const check = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(arr).filter(([key]) => !rexDigits.test(key))
);
expect(check).to.deep.equal(expectedValue);
```

That filters out the array index properties (roughly speaking, that's not an exact match for the definition of an [array index](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#array-index) but it's probably good enough for our purposes here) before doing the `to.deep.equal` check.